# Can not Download Glassfish on Netbeans

Tags: netbeans, glassfish

[image]

I am facing this problem in the picture above. I have done the same many times before. But know I have stuck to this error. I use Windows 10 and Netbeans 8.2 can anyone help?

Answer (score 4):

I reproduced your problem in NetBeans 8.2 and NetBeans 9.0 RC1. It is a bug and I have reported it: [NETBEANS-997 Unable to download and create GlassFish server](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NETBEANS-997)

Fortunately there is a simple workaround:

- First, [download Glassfish](https://javaee.github.io/glassfish/download) outside of NetBeans as a zip file.
- Unzip it to a suitable directory.
- On the **Add Server Instance** screen in NetBeans, click **Browse...** and select the directory containing the unzipped GlassFish files .

Comment: cant add anything it says i first must install the plugin lol